# Zune Player api

Tags: c++, zune

Is there the equivalent of the Windows Media Player SDK for the Zune Player software? I would like to be able to control the volume, play/pause state, and skip to next / previous track.

Comment: Did anyone learn how to initialize the database?

Comment: I was able to add support for Zune Player to FreezBeat via MediaKeys emulation. When I add track notification, I'll revisit this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Zune API but i dont know if it can do that... and its not documented so i never got it to work..

http://soapitstop.com/blogs/fleamarket/archive/2008/03/03/read-the-zune-collection-in-net-from-zune-s-own-api.aspx

But the post is outdated the zuneLib.Initialize() takes a parameter and i have no idear what to put there.. if you figure it out share please!

Comment: Excellent! I used redgate's reflector, the updated signature of that function is public unsafe int modopt(IsLong) Initialize(string path, out bool dbRebuilt). The path appears to be the path to the zune's media database. I'm looking for a C++ API though that may be too much to ask for !

Comment: where is the zune media database? if you know that?